# How to combine string from one column to another column at same index in pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp

I was doing a project in nlp.
My input is:

```
index  name  lst 
0      a     c    
0            d    
0            e    
1            f    
1      b     g
```

I need output like this:

```
index  name  lst combine  
0      a     c    a c 
0            d    a d  
0            e    a e  
1            f    b f  
1      b     g    b g
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: do you mind sharing the source data as a dict: ``df.to_dict('records')``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby`+`transform('max')` to replace the empty cells with the letter per group as the letters have precedence over space. The rest is a simple string concatenation per column:

```
df['combine'] = df.groupby('index')['name'].transform('max') + ' ' + df['lst']
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'index': [0,0,0,1,1],
                   'name': ['a','','','','b'],
                   'lst': list('cdefg'),
                  })
```

*NB. I considered "index" to be a column here, if this is the index you should use `df.index` in the `groupby`*

Output:

```
   index name lst combine
0      0    a   c     a c
1      0        d     a d
2      0        e     a e
3      1        f     b f
4      1    b   g     b g
```